# UTF-8 error attempting to read e-mail message: "Can't make <> of <> id 9574 of <> "INBOX" of <> "Gmail" into type <>."

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to retrieve the body of any e-mail that triggers my AppleScript.  I have a test message saved, and when I click "Apply Rules", I get this error:

"Can't make <> of <> id 9574 of <> "INBOX" of <> "Gmail" into type <>."

EDIT:  Here's the relevant portion of the code:

```
using terms from application "Mail"
on perform mail action with messages messageList for rule aRule
    tell application "Mail"
        repeat with thisMessage in messageList
            try
                say content of thisMessage
            on error errMsg
                display alert errMsg
            end try
        end repeat
    end tell
end perform mail action with messages
end using terms from
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
say (content of thisMessage as text)
```